# Why was this Star Wars canonicity question reopened?

Tags: discussion

This question was posted yesterday.

[What's the canonicity of Lucas's former "word-of-God" statements?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116562/whats-the-canonicity-of-lucass-former-word-of-god-statements/116589#116589)

After a few minutes consideration, I closed the question as a dupe of this wider question of Star Wars canon

[How is canonicity of derivative works determined for Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars)

However, it was then *reopened* (without edit) by several active users.

My question is *why*.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - My answer does now **explictly** address statements made in interviews and commentaries by those involved in the making of the films.

Comment: Because it's a schmuck.

Answer (score 10):

I saw this question in the re-open queue and voted to re-open.

As indicated by the fact that you had to take a few minutes to consider (and so did I), this is a tricky question because it's certainly very closely related to the first question. The difference, as I see it, is that the first question is asking about works that make in-universe statements, whereas the new question was asking about out-of-universe commentary by the original creator of the franchise. The first question also did not specifically ask about statements made by George Lucas, which is the focus of the new question.

Ultimately, I voted to re-open because I'd prefer to err on the side of keeping closely related questions open. After I'd thought about it and made my decision to re-open, I noticed that other users had already voted to re-open (four by the time I reviewed it, if I remember correctly). This indicated to me that my decision to re-open was more likely correct, and that other users seemed interested in a distinct answer for the new question.

I still think it should remain open, but I won't lose sleep if it is closed again.

Comment: I've edited it to include an explicit reference to interviews and commentaries.